# Batch polar coordinate conversion

Tags: gimp, batch-processing

I need to convert many files of the same size to polar projections. This is easy to do in GIMP with the Polar Coordinates plugin (Filters > Distorts > Polar Coordinates). However, I'm not sure how to either automate or batch this process.

I know that it is possible to script the automation and there is a commonly suggested batch processing plug-in called [BIMP](https://alessandrofrancesconi.it/projects/bimp/). However, both options call the "plug-in-polar-coords" procedure which does not act the same way in script as it does in the GIMP GUI. Below is an example:

I need to go from files that look like this (courtesy of  [Flickr user gadl](http://www.flickr.com/photos/gadl/) ([Alexandre Duret-Lutz](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/%7Eadl/)) under [CC BY-NC-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/2.0/)):

[image: Stretched image of Phare du Paon, île de Bréhat by Alexandre Duret-Lutz]

...to images that look like this:

[image: Polar projected image of Phare du Paon, île de Bréhat by Alexandre Duret-Lutz]

Which I've done with these settings in GIMP GUI:

[image: Screenshot of GIMP polar coordinate window]

Now I need to figure out how to do this with multiple images. I tried to use [BIMP](https://alessandrofrancesconi.it/projects/bimp/) with the manipulation "plug-in-polar-coords" but it does not provide an option to map the image to a circle as in the Polar Coordinates window (i.e. the "To polar" radio button).

[image: Screen shot of BIMP manipulation window]

And outputs files that look like this:

[image: Distorted polar projected image of Phare du Paon, île de Bréhat by Alexandre Duret-Lutz]

Any thoughts on how to do this? I would prefer solutions in GIMP but will also accept solutions in Inkscape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plug-ins are mostly implementing the Gimp 2.8 GUI. You would just need to set circle depth to 100% and "Polar to rectangular" to "False"

Demonstration: in the Gimp 2.8 UI I get the same output as you with these parameters:

[image]

And to get the picture you want I change to these:

[image]

To be more complete, using in 2.10 the same API as BIMP:

[image]

Comment: Have you actually tried this? For me, it does not produce a circularized image.

Comment: I don't use BIMP but it works if I use the same parameters on my Gimp 2.8 copy, and your screenshot doesn't show that you are using these values. See enhanced answer

Answer (score 4):

So I know next to nothing about Gimp, but you could do this in [Imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/), which as long as you're able to install, should be as easy as copy&pasting the code into the command line and pressing enter.

```
cd "path to your input folder"
mkdir "../output" 

mogrify \
  -path "../output" \
  -rotate '180' \
  +distort Polar 0 \
  -virtual-pixel 'horizontal-tile' \
  -background 'black' \
  -quality 100 \
  -format jpg *
```

[image]

**Explanations**

- `cd ""` - Input path goes here. You should be able to drag a folder into the command line window to get its path.
- `mkdir ""` - Makes a folder. In this case the output folder.
- mogrify

  - [`path ""`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#path) - Path to output folder. `../` traverses one level up from the input folder.
  - [`rotate`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#rotate) - This is used so the polar distort makes a globe. I don't know if distort would have an option for flipping the image but this works.
  - [`distort`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#distort) [`Polar`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#polar) - Polar distort
  - [`virtual-pixel`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#virtual-pixel) - This option defines what color source should be used if and when a color lookup completely 'misses' the source image.
  - [`background`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#background)
  - [`quality`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality)
  - [`format`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#format) - Output format.
  - `\` is used to split the mogrify command into multiple lines so it's easier to read.

Comment: I use imagemagick in my website for basic image upload resizing, I had no idea it could do anything that fancy!  I will have to look at that plugin more and see what else it can do.